# How to check if files on svn are the same with the local files C#(sharpsvn)

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

I'm using the SharpSvn library. I want to check if the files that I have locally are the same with those on the subversion server. Does anyone know how I do this?
Currently this is what I'm trying to do but it is saying "Unable to connect to a repository at URL"

```
    public bool IsDirectoryTheSame(string folderpath)
    {
        var IsSameDirectory = false;
        var installfolderlocal = GetInstallationFolder(folderpath);
        using (SvnClient svnClient = new SvnClient())
        {
            SvnUriTarget target1 =
                new SvnUriTarget(
                    new Uri(string.Format("{0}{1}", svnclientpath, folderpath)));
            SvnUriTarget target2 =
                new SvnUriTarget(
                    new Uri(installfolderlocal));

            using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
            IsSameDirectory =  svnClient.Diff(target1,target2,stream);
            }
        }
        return IsSameDirectory;
    }
```

Comment: You could compare the Checksums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming from your question that the local files are version controlled, in which case you can use GetInfo() to get the latest revision number for the file in the repository and compare that with the latest revision number for your local file.

[Another suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13500552/1123294) would be to use GetUriFromWorkingCopy(). I personally haven't tested it myself, but it's worth a shot.

At any rate, you should use diffing as a last resort since that can be an expensive call. If the file is not version-controlled, though, that may be your only shot.

Comment: Committing a file to check if it is changed isn't really a useful solution.

Comment: Yes, I removed that half of the answer because, as you said, the users is not looking to commit the change itself.